# How to set the current\working directory of a WPF application to the installation path

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

In my C# WPF application I need to access some configuration files via a 3rd party library. This library requires to have the configuration file located in the same folder as the executable of my application. So i have no chance to change this behaviour.
While running my application in Visual Studio 2013 it works fine. I can access the configuration file since I have just copied it to the relevant folder.

But if I install my application an run it it cant locate my configuration files because it tries to find it under: Windows\system32.

No my approach is to make it happen that my application looks for the configuration file in the applications install folder.

How can I do that? How can I set the current\working directory of my application to a specific (installation) path in Visual Studio 2013?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();
```

This will give path like `"c:\\program...\\installdir\\"` where your .exe is located.